# How to store an entity together with its relations?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Imagine the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String manufacturer;

    private String model;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "car")
    private Set<Tire> tires = new HashSet<>();

    // Getters & setters

}

@Entity
public class Tire {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "car_id")
    private Car car;

    // Getters & setters

}
```

I create a new `Car` and add some new `Tire`s to it. Then I try to save that car
using the `save()` method of a `JpaRepository<Car, Long>`. The car gets persisted
but not the tires. I already tried to add `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` to the
`@OneToMany` annotation, but it had no effect. So how can I store the tires?

Comment: CascadeType is the way to go. Did you try CascadeType.ALL and check your DAO classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set [`CascadeType`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html) on the `OneToMany` relation.

Comment: Ups, I didn't add the tires collection to the car.

Comment: I wanted to ask that, but I was afraid it would offend you :)